# Parsing a string into an array for C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

How do I parse a string into an array in C++?

For example: `"[1:2:3:4]cd/dvd  PLDS  DVD-RW DU8A6SH DU53  /dev/sr0"`

I want to get an array of integers inside the square bracket `[]`. So the array contains `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.

Below is the code I wrote, but I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to approach it.

```
std::string test = "[1:2:3:4]cd/dvd  PLDS  DVD-RW DU8A6SH DU53  /dev/sr0";
int begin = test.find("[");
begin = begin + 1;
std::string sub = test.substr(begin,7);
std::replace(sub.begin(), sub.end(), ':', ' ');

std::vector<int> arr;
std::stringstream ss(sub);
int temp;
while (ss >> temp)
     arr.push_back(temp);
```

Note: Something will not be before `"["`. `"["` will always be present. The numbers will always be one digit each. There will always be four integers inside the square brackets. `"]"` will always be present. Text always follows after the `"]"`.

Comment: Edit your question and provide a more detailed problem statement. Will something be before the `[`? Will a `[` always be present? Will the numbers always be 1 character? Will the separator always be a `:`? Will a `]` always be present? Will text always follow the `]`?

Comment: The array will have a fixed number of elements, won't it? In that case, you don't even need/want a vector of ints, but an `std::array`, or better yet - a structure/class with meaningful field names.

Comment: Something will not be before [. Yes, [ will be present. Yes the numbers will always be one digit. Yes ] always be present. The text always follow the after ]

Comment: As @einpoklum asked, will the numbers always be 4? Do you really want a `std::vector<int>`? Maybe other choices could be better. In any case, edit your question and add the additional details there, don't leave the details on comments.

Comment: Yes. The there will be four numbers inside square bracket. I will edit my question. Thanks @Costantino Grana

Comment: Check the answers and if any of them is fine, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints you added you can try this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string test = "[1:2:3:4]cd/dvd  PLDS  DVD-RW DU8A6SH DU53  /dev/sr0";

    std::vector<int> v(4);
    {
        char open_square_bracket, colon1, colon2, colon3, close_square_bracket;
        std::stringstream ss(test);
        ss >> open_square_bracket >> v[0] >> colon1 >> v[1] >> colon2 >> v[2] >> colon3 >> v[3] >> close_square_bracket;
    }

    copy(begin(v), end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Of course the important part is the one I put in the block statement, to highlight it. This allows you to also check if the characters are what they are supposed to be. Otherwise, if you are 100% sure the format will be correct it can be simplified to

```
    std::vector<int> v(4);
    char c;
    std::stringstream ss(test);
    ss >> c >> v[0] >> c >> v[1] >> c >> v[2] >> c >> v[3] >> c;
```

You can also wrap this in a for loop, but if it's always 4 elements, why bother?

Of course, in this case an `std::array<>` may be used:

```
    std::array<int, 4> v;
    char c;
    std::stringstream ss(test);
    ss >> c >> v[0] >> c >> v[1] >> c >> v[2] >> c >> v[3] >> c;
```

Run it on [ideone](https://ideone.com/wWKRkw).

Comment: Thank you so much @Costantino Grana! I am new to c++ and I want to learn more about the stringstream. Does the stringstream knows that the char open_square_bracket, ...  are '[' , ':'  and ']'? Also, is there any reason why you have { } underneath the std::vector<int> v(4)?

Comment: No, as I wrote later, that was just for the case you wanted to check if `open_square_bracket=='['`, then if `colon1==':'` and so on. The `{` and `}` were there just to highlight the part of interest and to avoid letting variables `c` and `ss` live longer than needed.

Comment: @Br0sk1 "*Does the stringstream knows that the char open_square_bracket, ... are '[' , ':' and ']'?*" - no, it does not.  Only that you asked it to read a `char` so it does, then read an `int` so it does, then read a `char` so it does, etc. It is up to you to validate that each `char` read is what you are expecting it to be.

Comment: Moreover, all `std::istream` versions read integers up to the next character that cannot be part of an integer (spaces, letters or punctuation). So when they reach a `:` they will stop. So the next `>> c` extracts the `:` char.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Thanks! I learned a lot from this convo!

Comment: Use an `std::array` please.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hard-coding the size of `substr()`, that implies the numbers have fixed positions and widths, in which case you could simply use this instead:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <array>

std::string test = "[1:2:3:4]cd/dvd  PLDS  DVD-RW DU8A6SH DU53  /dev/sr0";

std::array<int, 4> arr; // or: int arr[4]; pre-C++11
for(int i = 1, j = 0; i < 9; i += 2, ++j)
    arr[j] = test[i]-'0';
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/FRy4Hq)

However, if that is not the case, then don't make assumptions about where the closing `]` is located.  Use `find()` to locate it, eg:

```cpp
std::string test = "[1:2:3:4]cd/dvd  PLDS  DVD-RW DU8A6SH DU53  /dev/sr0";

std::string::size_type begin = test.find('[') + 1;
std::string::size_type end = test.find(']', begin);
std::string sub = test.substr(begin, end - begin);

std::vector<int> arr;
std::istringstream iss(sub);
int temp;

while (iss >> temp) {
    arr.push_back(temp);
    iss.ignore();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/rMejs4)

If you are using C++17 or later, you can use a `std::string_view` and `std::from_chars()` to reduce memory overhead, so you don't have to allocate a separate `std::string` for the `sub` or `std::istringstream`, or even use a `std::istringstream` at all, eg:

```cpp
std::string test = "[1:2:3:4]cd/dvd  PLDS  DVD-RW DU8A6SH DU53  /dev/sr0";
std::string_view sv(test.data(), test.size());

std::string_view::size_type begin = sv.find('[') + 1;
std::string_view::size_type end = sv.find(']', begin);
std::string_view sub = sv.substr(begin, end - begin);

std::vector<int> arr;
const char *pBegin = sub.data(), *pEnd = pBegin + sub.size();
int temp;

while (pBegin < pEnd)
{
    auto [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(pBegin, pEnd, temp);
    if (ec != std::errc()) break;
    arr.push_back(temp);
    pBegin = ptr + 1;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RkEbANYxpAnymw1g)

Comment: For the second option you wrote, why do you not need this "std::replace(sub.begin(), sub.end(), ':', ' ')"? Or does the istringstream just gets the integer somehow? I am new to this so any help would be nice.

Comment: @Br0sk1 Because `operator>>` stops reading when it reaches a character that doesn't belong to the type that is being read. That includes whitespace. In my example, `operator>>` will stop reading when it reaches a `:` character, or the end of the string. The subsequent call to `iss.ignore()` to used to skip that `:` character before `operator>>` is called again.

Comment: That makes so much more sense now! Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    std::string str = "[1:2:3:4]aaa";
    std::vector<int> str_chars = {};

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        char curr = str.at(i);
        if (str.at(i) == '[')
        {
            str_chars.push_back((str.at(i + 1) - '0'));
        }
        else if ((str.at(i) == ':'))
        {
            str_chars.push_back(str.at(i + 1) - '0');
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str_chars.size(); ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", str_chars.at(i));
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would there be a problem if I change the vector<char> to vector<int>?

Comment: you need to do the following to convert the chars into integers: `char c = '1'; int c2 = c - '0'`

Comment: alright, i have edited the code to give you the integers instead of characters

Comment: The repeated use of `str.at(...)` is overkill, use `str[...]` instead. Also, `str.at(i + 1)` will raise an exception if `i` is at the last char in the string, since the loop does not stop when it reaches `]`

Comment: Indeed I just whipped it up in 1 minute. Also I believe at does bound checking so I use it more frequently myself, but [] works too

Comment: @Hjkl Yes, `at()` does bounds checking, but that is already being handled by the `for` loop, so `at()` is just wasted overhead.

Comment: I'll make sure to tell OP to change the .at(i + 1) into [i + 1] when I see him at the next alcoholics anonymous meeting